# $a + b + c + d = 1$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = \frac{1}{3}$, where $-1 \le a,b,c,d \le 1$. Which value of $a$ is the largest possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, constraints

I'm a complete novice who honestly has no clue about how to solve these types of problems. This question was originally multiple choice, and I was able to get the answer $\frac12$ simply through process of elimination.
I would appreciate any help, pointing in the right direction.

Comment: If you know multi-variable calculus, then this is a Lagrange multiplier problem with two constraints.

Comment: While I don't know that much multivariable calculus, any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to maximize is $f(a,b,c,d)=a$.  The constraints are $g(a,b,c,d) = a+b+c+d=1$ and $h(a,b,c,d) = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = \frac{1}{3}.$  So we solve the system

$$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g +\mu \nabla h$$

which is

$$1 = \lambda + \mu 2a$$
$$0 = \lambda + \mu 2b$$
$$0 = \lambda + \mu 2c$$
$$0 = \lambda + \mu 2d$$

plus the two constraint equations.  $6$ equations in $6$ variables.  From the last 3 equations we see that $b=c=d.$ That makes the first constraint $a+3b=1$ and the second $a^2+3b^2 = \frac{1}{3}$ to get $a=0$ or $a=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange multiplier ansatz is powerful and quickly gives an answer, as demonstrated by B. Goddard:
$\,a=\frac12$ and $\,b=c=d=\frac16\,$ does the job.

The given constraints may be connected by means of the Inequality between Arithmetic and Quadratic mean
$$1-a \:=\: b+c+d \:\leqslant\: |b|+|c|+|d| \:\leqslant\:
3\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2+d^2}3} \:=\: \sqrt{1-3a^2}\,.$$
Squaring & rearranging yields
$\:4a^2\leqslant2a\,,$
hence $\,a\,$ cannot be larger than $\frac12\,$.